# Constructing coordinate maps on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, coordinate-systems

I've been studying differential geometry for a little while now, but I've never properly justified to myself rigorously the need to consider other more general coordinate maps, other than Cartesian on a manifold with a metric defined on it (or indeed in general, without a metric). Am I correct in saying that the Cartesian coordinate system is a special kind of mapping which directly relates the intrinsic distance between two points on a manifold to the 'numerical' distance between their coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. As, in general, a coordinate patch on a manifold will have a non-Euclidean geometry, although it will be possible to construct a one-to-one mapping such that these points can be labeled by coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, it will not be possible to construct a map that preserves the intrinsic distance between two points in this patch such that it corresponds to the 'coordinate distance' between their corresponding coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. In other words, although we will be able to construct a coordinate map, it will be impossible to construct a Cartesian coordinate map for this patch, which requires a Euclidean metric (apart from within a small neighbourhood around each point in this patch)?

N.B. By "Cartesian coordinate system" I mean the usual coordinate system used for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in which the geometry is flat (i.e. has a Euclidean metric)

Comment: What do you mean by "Cartesian coordinate system" on a differential manifold?

Comment: @A.P.  I mean the standard Cartesian coordinate map that one usually uses to map Euclidean space (with the Euclidean metric) to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. This can be used on more general manifolds right?

Comment: Not really. A coordinate system, or atlas, on a (real) manifold $M$ is a set $\{(U_{\alpha},\varphi_{\alpha})\}$ where $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ is an open covering of $M$ and $\varphi_{\alpha}: U_{\alpha} \to V_{\alpha}$ are homeomorphisms, with $V_{\alpha}$ an open set of $\Bbb{R}^n$. The definition of differential manifold has just a couple of extra conditions. Then you can use $\varphi_{\alpha}^{-1}$ to get local coordinates $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ such that $\varphi_{\alpha}^{-1}(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = m \in U_{\alpha}$, but that's it.

Comment: @A.P.   I was trying to motivate when one has a notion of distance (i.e. a metric) defined on a given manifold why one would ever choose to use coordinate systems other than Cartesian ones. I've read that in general it is not possible to construct such a map (i.e. a Cartesian one) on a curved manifold as the manifold will be non-Euclidean in any given coordinate patch. I was trying to heuristically motivate the idea from a physicists background, approaching differential geometry for use in general relativity?!

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "Cartesian coordinate system". If you are talking about the usual coordinate system on $\Bbb{R}^n$, then the only meaningful way to define a similar thing on a manifold is the one I just described. The only analogy I can give you is this one: in $\Bbb{R}^n$ every point is the intersection of $n$ orthogonal lines, and the Cartesian system associates a tuple of real numbers to each point by fixing a reference point and defining a length function on each of those lines.

Comment: ...(cont.) You can think of the local coordinate functions $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ I described above as lengths of arcs of "special" curves with respect to a fixed (local) reference point; those curves are special in the sense that every point in $U_{\alpha}$ is the intersection of $n$ of those lines. An example of those special curves on a sphere are meridians and parallels, and in this case $U_{\alpha}$ is the whole sphere minus the North and South poles.

Comment: @A.P.   Yes, by Cartesian coordinate system I mean the usual rectilinear coordinate system defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the Euclidean metric. I think my confusion arises from the description of a manifold as being locally mappable to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that one can assign coordinates to points in a given patch on the manifold. In my naivety I have, in the past, always associated  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with Euclidean (flat) space...

Comment: ...in which case it is always possible to use Cartesian coordinates and so why would one ever want to use other coordinate maps (other than that they may simplify things/be more convenient)?!

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem lies in that "locally mappable": a space which is homeomorphic (or even diffeomorphic) to $\Bbb{R}^n$ isn't necessarily flat, but it can be deformed into $\Bbb{R}^n$ with a sufficiently regular transformation. Not to mention that the various charts need to "glue" together. To understand this better, try to check that on a ($2$-dimensional) sphere the stereographic projections from the North and South pole form a coordinate system. Moreover, the sphere doesn't contain any straight segments.

Comment: You should then see that what you call "Cartesian coordinate system" is exactly what I described in my previous comments.

Comment: @A.P.   So, for example, if one considers a patch on a manifold in which the geometry is non-Euclidean (assuming a metric is defined), then in order to be able to ascribe each point in such a patch with coordinates, we have to deform this patch to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that we can label each point by an element in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? ...

Comment: ... Would it be correct to say that in general we would use coordinate systems (for example, spherical polar) other than Cartesian as, in general, by deforming this patch to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ we will not preserve the intrinsic distance between two points in this patch (as the geometry is non-Euclidean) ...

Comment: ... and hence it will not be possible to find a Cartesian coordinate map as this requires the distance between points to be preserved by the mapping to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that the intrinsic distance between two points (in this patch on the manifold) is equal to the "distance" between their coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? (I've been reading a bit from this link: http://www.iep.utm.edu/proper-t/#H3   Section 4 on Cartesian coordinates)

Comment: Is the point that generally given a chosen patch on a manifold (with a non-Euclidean metric defined) it is not possible to construct an invertible map between points on the manifold (in this patch) that is Cartesian?